# How to add 'created_at' and 'updated_at' columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to add 'updated_at' and 'created_at' columns to some already existing table in MySQL database. I've added those colums using MySQL Workbench, but what query should I use to make them work properly? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What do you mean with "make them work properly"?

Comment: I mean to make them fill automatically when they should - I've added them just as "normal" fields

Comment: kacper@sudo-rm-rf:~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 117, accepted):

According to the reference [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)* you can use the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clauses in column definitions:

> With **both** DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   the column has the current timestamp for its default value and is
>   automatically updated to the current timestamp.

whereas:

> With a DEFAULT clause but **no** ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clause, the
>   column has the given default value and is not automatically updated to
>   the current timestamp.

So, for example, you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

To add the columns to an already existing table you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE t1
ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
ADD COLUMN updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

**Note:** Link provided refers to MySQL 8.0. The syntax is the same for previous versions as well. There is some difference though for versions prior to 5.6.5. Just quoting from the [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) again:

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically
>   initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
>   current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and
>   for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked! :D

Comment: I preffer triggers, more portable, with strict behaviour etc...

Comment: any reason that created_at is a TIMESTAMP and updated_at is a DATETIME ?

Comment: @CharlieMartin No, I just wanted to show that both can be used. Normally `TIMESTAMP` is the preferred type for tracking changes to rows.

Comment: Can you help me to understand why the columns are using a different type?  `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME`, is it due the ON UPDATE clause?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use a Trigger. As example, when creating a new entry, the trigger will be activated and will execute, like an event in c# or an Action listener in Java!

With them, you can update that new entry with a creation date, or an edited date when you manipulated an entry. [See this Documentation on how to use MySql Triggers on w3resource.](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php)